# Boostrap datetimepicker not pre-filling date

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using Boostrap datetime picker to make reservations in fullcalendar.
I would like to pre-fill my datetime piker with the selected date and time when clicking the calendar.

With the following code I can pre-fill the time but not the date and I don't know why. I found that I should just change the format I want to display, but after doing that, the date is not being pre-filled.

```js
select: function(inform) {
                var date_from= new Date(inform.startStr);
                var date_to= new Date(inform.endStr) ;
                let currentDate = new Date();
                
                if (date_from >= currentDate) {
                    $('#exampleModalToggle').modal('show');
                    console.log(' date clicked bigger than current date, you can do reservation')
                    $(".fc-highlight").css("background", "#ffc800", "important!"); 
                    
                    
                    $(function() {
                        $("#start_date_picker").datetimepicker({
                            format: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                            locale: "fr",
                            useCurrent:false, 
                            defaultDate: date_from,
                        });
                        
                        $("#start_hour_picker").datetimepicker({
                            format: 'HH:mm',
                            useCurrent:false, 
                            defaultDate: date_from,
                        });
                        
                        $("#end_date_picker").datetimepicker({
                            format: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                            useCurrent:false,
                            defaultDate: date_to,
                        });
                        
                        $("#end_hour_picker").datetimepicker({
                            format: 'HH:mm',
                            useCurrent:false, 
                            defaultDate: date_to,
                        })
                    });

                } 
            },
```

```html
<!--Start Date-->
 <div id="start_date"  class="add_reservation_subtitles pb-3" style="margin-left: 28px;">
                                <input id="start_date_input" data-provide="datepicker" name="start_date" type="date"
                                    lang="fr" id="datepicker_second" class="datepicker1" style="margin-left: 28px;" required>
                                <input name="start_hour" type="time" lang="fr" class="timepicker modal_rigth_elements"
                                    required>
                            </div>
                     
 <!--End Date-->
  <div id="end_date" style="margin-left: 28px;" class="add_reservation_subtitles pb-3 ">
                                <input id="end_date_input" type="date" lang="fr" class="date-picker"
                                    style="margin-left: 28px;" required>
                                <input name="end_hour" type="time" lang="fr" class="timepicker modal_rigth_elements"
                                    required>
                            </div>
```

I have tried different formats, like yyyy-mm-dd, 'mm-dd-yyyy' , 'mm/dd/yyyy' and nothing is working. I don't even have error messages. So I don't know what is happening.

I'm using  this datetimepicker :

```
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
```

Thansk a lot for all your help

Comment: Date format should probably be `YYYY-MM-DD`. It uses momentJS format strings, which are described here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: @ADyson !! thanks a loot! It works ^^